# Retrofit - is it Possible for expecting either String or Object in response

Tags: json, android-studio, retrofit2

I have to request to API that by default returning an Object and there is a section "more" that is could be Object or String depends on some data sent. It is on purposes to create like that, not created by me of course.

```
{
    ...
    "list": {
        ...
        "more": {
            "header": {
                "a": "..."
            },
            "request": {
                ...
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Above is typical response that I get from API, that list more is an Object. But, sometimes it would return like the below one while of course it would led me to an error.

```
{
    ...
    "list": {
        ...
        "more": "no data available"
            
    }
}
```

I just curious is it possible to handle it since retrofit immediately throwing error if response not exactly same as POJO ? <strike>or can I utilized Any to make it possible ?</strike> since if I change POJO to String it would led me to an error if response was an Object.

> Let's not forget about how I request the response. I could provide it,
> but is it necessary for this question ? if it is then ask me I will.

> Change POJO to Any is not Possible since Parcelize is not supported this Type.

## EDIT

Since there is asking what error I would receive, then I will make it readable here.

If I set it as string it would be ok if response was String but if it's Object it would return.

> java.lang.IllegalStateException:Excepted a string but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 4363 $.list.more

and it would do otherwise if I set it to object but it was returning String

> java.lang.IllegalStateException:Excepted a object but was String at line 1 column 4363 $.list.more

Comment: what is the error you are getting? Nothing is wrong with the api responses, both are ok. Single pojo can handle both the response.

Comment: editted question for readable version

Comment: you know the error, it is related to parsing the response. You need to handle parsing. And you always receive string in response. Make changes in your pojo.

Comment: ah you are right.